# How do update the mobile restaurant menu on Google My Business?

Tags: google, local-seo, google-my-business

I added our restaurant menu to a Google listing.  The issue with the listing is that there is a second party that has linked to the mobile menu. That mobile menu has not been updated in Google My Business.

If there is an area to update the Google mobile menu, a link would be helpful.

http://www.olympicpizzavt.com/Olympic_Pizza_Menu.html

Comment: You mean sitelinks? or the right panel info? you should know that Google may never return the menu and there is no way of prompting Google to list it other than build your local reputation.

Comment: Furthermore `Olympic_Pizza_Menu.html` is not valid HTML. Missing `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` and you have `<h2>` in ul as child and unclosed `<li>`. If you want every chance possible then fix your code. etc etc. If the menu is fetched using AJAX then ensure you closed of your `</li>` and `</ul>`.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100780/google-mobile-search-for-client-restaurant-is-showing-incorrect-text-menu-as-par/100799#100799